# Java String Util - Numeric replace issue

Tags: java

I have string with numeric letter and sending it to below code , its parsing the with % symbol.

**Example :**

```
at3t - at%t    -   Incorrect
at34t - at%%t   -  Incorrect
```

**Expectation :**

```
at3t - at3t  - Correct
at34t - at34t - Correct
at234ert vbnm - (at234ert) String 1 and (vbnm) String2 - Correct
stack overflow - stack -string1 and overflow - String2  - Correct

String aName =StringUtils.lowerCase(aNumber.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "%"));
```

if any string "Stack overflow" - its converting to stack as first and overflow as second..No issue. I looking for same method but no need to replace the numeric.

Please advise.

Comment: you are replacing what is not a letter with % , what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why if numeric comes , string replacing % symbol

```
Number.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "%")
```

You are doing a replace of all non `a-zA-Z` characters with a `%`  I don't see how you expect the code to do anything else.

If you want to split the string by spaces I suggest you use split.

```
String line = "stack overflow";
String[] words = line.toLowerCase().split(" "); 
// words[0] = "stack", soreds[1] = "overflow"
```

Comment: I able to use like - String aName =StringUtils.lowerCase(Number.split(" "));

Comment: @user2444474 `String` already has a built in `toLowerCase()` method. See my answer.

Comment: Error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String" - Please advise how to handle error here ? Have updated the code in question section.

Comment: @user2444474 Read my answer again !? ;) Convert to lower case, before splitting it.

Comment: Number.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "%")) - Method is good when string is "Stack overflow". So what i expecting i don't want to do when string comes with numberic.other than that its looks good.

Comment: @user2444474 What that expression does appears to be unrelated to the question. You show many examples of where it is wrong, can you give an example of where it does the right thing?